# .net file load exception: nuget .net standard 1.6 vs .net40 client

Tags: .net, f#

I have a project A, a .net standard 2.0 library,
and project B (Console application 4.5 .net framework) that references project A.

I added library C (FParsecCS 1.03) via nuget to both project A and project B.

Project A and Project B compile.

When running I get:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException could not load library C  or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest does not match the assembly reference.
```

The file FParsecCS.dll is in the bin\debug directory!

How can I solve this?  I don't think I need to do any redirection.

I have removed the library, closed the solution,  reopened the solution, re-build, and the problem remains.

**Work around**:

I found a work around if I go to user folder .nuget \packages\library C\lib\netstandadrd1.6 and copy the dll to the bin\debug of the exe it works.

By default  it seems to copy the lib\net40-client? how can I force it to copy and use the .netstandard1.6?